# Failing to migrate a .NET C++ class library from VS 2008 to VS 2012

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a C++ project that builds a .NET class library that targets the framework 3.5.

This project has been working seamlessly since ages and the classes can be used from, among others, C# applications. It was developed with Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

Now I need to migrate if to Visual Studio 2012 Professional. I have successfully converted the project.

I meet a first problem, which is that the target framework cannot be changed from the project Common Properties, the field is read-only.

I can work around this by editing the .vcxproj file to insert a TargetedFramework tag. The new version does appear in the Common Properties.

I am also able to add references to the .NET assemblies that the library needs (just System, System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms). The class library compiles correctly to a Dll and I can see its content in the Object Browser.

Now if I try to use it in an application targeting a framework version below 4, I get the message

```
1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets(1605,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "MyClasses" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
```

I can't see where an indirect reference could come from (my explicit references are to v2.0.50727, which seem to be the file version for 2.0/3.0/3.5).

Do you have any explanation ?

Comment: Targeting .NET 4 is a rock-hard requirement for VS2012, the linker emits assembly references.  If you must target 3.5 then you have to keep using VS2008.

Comment: This is strange. For a C# application, you can select any version from 2.0 up to 4.6. Do you mean that this is a limitation of VC++ ?

Comment: It is entirely by design, C++/CLI needs AppDomain related glue code in the CRT to ensure unmanaged state is initialized correctly, done by a module initializer.  That code always produces a reference to mscorlib and System, the 4.0 versions for VS2010 and up, you can't wish it away.

Comment: One slight correction to Hans's wording: VS2012 vs its bundled C++ compiler.  Visual Studio is a development environment version, and does NOT have to match the .NET framework version.  The VC++ compiler that ships with VS2012 does have the restriction Hans mentions, but you can use the VS2012 environment with the version of the C++ toolchain (compiler+linker+more) that shipped with VS2008, normally by having both VS versions installed on the same computer.  However, if you're doing that, I'd suggest using VS2015 + old platform toolset, so you get the greatly improved Intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Expanding on Hans's correct comments)

Visual Studio supports .NET multi-targeting for the C++/CLI language by launching older versions of the C++ compiler.

As a result, the language features are inextricably linked to the .NET framework dependency -- with the newer compilers (Visual C++ 2010 and later), you get C++11 and C++14 features and .NET 4, with the older compilers (Visual C++ 2008 and before) you get .NET 2, but very little C++11 support.

To control this, there's a Platform Toolset selection in the Project Properties, but some manual project file editing is also required.

The Visual C++ Team wrote a blog post about [C++ Managed Multi-Targeting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/11/22/framework-multi-targeting-for-vc-projects.aspx) in Visual Studio 2010... for later versions, read [the documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Then I assume it makes little difference to build straight from VC2008 or VC2010/2012 with the previous platform toolset...

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Microsoft is getting ready to release VS2015 Update 1 which has some really cool features that make using it + older platform toolset very worthwhile.  But for 2008 vs 2012... yeah I agree, it doesn't make much different which IDE you use.